# Flutter: force container height to Child's height

Tags: flutter

The container height is set to screen height with my code. I want to make this `Container` height to its child height.

Child's height differ from its condition. So, I don't want to set it at the certain fixed value. How can I set it to just cover its child height?

```
Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.orange,
                width: 0.7,
              ),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Column(
               Widgets.....
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
              ],
            ),
          );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `mainAxisSize` property on it's child (`Column`) as following

```
Container(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.85,
  // ...
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
      // ...
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I was trying everything for 4 hours. It was this easy! Still have to wait for few mins to accept the answer, but thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped! Happy coding

Comment: You rarely need MediaQuery.of(context).size.  Instead, use LayoutBuilder to get the constraints passed to you by the parent widget, which means automatic adjustment if the device is rotated or you decide to make a one-column layout into a two-column layout.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz OP just need to adjust the height of his `Container`. So I cannot change his Design

Comment: This answer more for OP then.  Made same mistake.

Comment: So, I can get the screen width size from the layoutbuilder as well?

Comment: Yes you can. Have a look at how to use it here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html